# Im trying to make a projector movie that links to a pdf. Im able to get it to work on a pc but not on mac

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Im trying to make a projector movie that links to a pdf (in the same folder) on a CD that needs to run in both windows and mac. Im able to get it to work on a pc but not on mac. here is the code for the button i used in the projector.

on (release) {
fscommand ("exec", "manual1.bat");

and bat file open a pdf file.

so i want to do the same thing for mac, that is using the fscommand to open up a pdf in acrobat. I read messages here that use applescript but i dont understand it too well so what id like to know if possible is the applescript, what it does and do i apply it to the button in my projector or do i tell the button to look at the applescript or what? I guess thats it for now.

thanks,
JOY

Comment: Work on your accept percentage. You've asked quite a few questions here and you've **never** marked any of those answers as correct. People will be much less willing to answer your questions if you won't give them credit for helping you.

Comment: I am really very sorry for that. Cause i don't know about the marked the answers.

Comment: if you create an AIR application instead of a projector, you could simply use the `openWithDefaultApplication()` method from flash.filesystem.File: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication%28%29

Comment: Thank you. i have finish this project. we are going to use this project only in windows.

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978, that would make a nice answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you create an AIR application instead of a projector, you could simply use the [openWithDefaultApplication()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication%28%29) method from [flash.filesystem.File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).